# Does the concept of infinity have any practical applications?

Tags: infinity, applications

I know what you're thinking: "of course it has, for example, it can be used to tell you how many times you can go around a circle". But that isn't really true, now is it? You'd be dead or the world would go under long before an infinite amount of loops had been reached.

Are there any practical applications for the concept of infinity? Is it a useful concept in maths at all?

I know that Donald E. Knuth has argued that for all practical purposes, a very, very large number has the same effect as infinity, in his book "Things a Computer Scientist Rarely Talks About" (can't remember the exact quote, nor find it online, unfortunately).

Examples are appreciated.

Comment: We can deal much better with $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$ than with $\sum_{n=0}^{10^{80}}\frac1{n^2}$.

Comment: Adding to Hagen Von Eitzen, taylor series are infinite series which cannot approximate perfectly when finite. If made finite, With accumulation of errors from one approximation to another, there might be devastating effects.

Comment: "As soon as you begin to understand the immensity of Super K, you will realize that just being finite isn't much of a limitation, and you will see how pointless are the philosopher's discussion about finite versus infinite. Infinity is a red herring. I would be perfectly happy to give up immortality if I could only live Super K years before dying. In fact, Super K nanoseconds would be enough." 
Super K is $10 \uparrow \uparrow \uparrow \uparrow 3$, D.E. Knuth, pages 171-172 of his "Things a computer scientist rarely talks about"; Stanford Calif.: Center for Study of Language and Inform., 2001.

Comment: Hagen von Eitzen, what if ∞ represented "a really, really large number" instead? Would not the calculations be the same and the ability to deal with it the same?

Comment: If you enjoy physics, look into black holes; as density goes to infinity, you end up with black holes!

Comment: One use is that infinity is a good approximation to very big, and infinitesimal is an approximation to very small. For example, we use continuous models to approximate discrete ones for very large numbers (continuous matter to approximate atoms, Gaussian law to approximate binomial laws...)

Comment: Possibly relevant to the question, an article about infinity in mathematics: https://www.quantamagazine.org/to-settle-infinity-question-a-new-law-of-mathematics-20131126/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the BBC's documentary about infinity they interviewed Doron Zeilberger which is probably the poster boy for "infinity is nonsense" in the world of mathematics.

They show him work with $\infty$ symbols when talking about series and functions. The reason this is a good idea is simple.

To say that something is infinite we just need to say that it has more elements than any finite number. But to say that something is finite we need to bound it somehow, which we cannot say in a simple way (and simple way means that for infinite we have a simple schema saying "more than $n$ distinct objects", whereas there is no particular schema catching all forms of finiteness).

In particular this is useful when talking about very small or very large things, it allows us to calculate limits (which is an essentially infinitary process) but discard most of the computation as a remainder which does not affect the outcome, which will follow by taking some error margin.

Comment: "it allows us to calculate limits (which is an essentially infinitary process)" - can you explain the parenthetical statement and what you mean by "infinitary" versus "finitary"? I've asked half a dozen mathematicians and nobody has provided a concrete answer.

Comment: When coming to calculate $2+3+5+7$ you simply add these numbers and get the result. This is a finite process of calculation. An infinitary process is one you can prove wha the result is going to be, but you don't, and can't, calculate *every* step in the way. For example you don't really write down the entire number produced by Cantor's diagonal argument. Limits are essentially infinitary because you don't calculate the result by hand, each step of the way, you make a general argument which allows you to prove something about the result.

Comment: But the derivative of $x^2$ is also a limit yet can be computed as $2x$ in a finite number of steps for example by symbolic software like Mathematica programmed with rules to manipulate such expressions. The expressions themselves are finite and so are the rules. But I see that you've modified infinitary by "essentially" so you have to explain that now.

Comment: You can define a formal method of deriving polynomials, which will then amount of a finite calculation. But you can't use this to derive $\sin x$; then you can add a rule for deriving $\sin$, but then you can't derive $\cos$; then you can add a rule ... and so on and so forth. But you can also introduce the definition of a derivative using a limit, then you can prove that this is a good notion, and that all those symbolic rules follow from it - and more. Now the reason I said "essentially" is that we can sometimes do a finite manipulations to derive the exact result. [cont.]

Comment: You can symbolically derive and integrate, and you can get to a close enough result and "clean it up" in some method to obtain a "nice" result (e.g. a polynomial). But this is not the definition of a derivative using limits. Similarly when calculating the limit of a sequence, you can't really calculate it. At best you can "guess" that it would have to be a certain value and then you can prove that this is the correct value. One good way of doing that, for example, is identifying the terms as some continuous function - when possible. But this is not *really* calculating, it bypasses calcuating.

Comment: Computers do nothing but calculate. And half the aim of math is to find shortcuts via abstract results. It's not "cleaning up", "get close enough" or "guess": $2x$ is not an approximation of the derivative of $x^2$, it's *the* exact, unique, limit value.

Comment: Re: "you can't use this to derive sin $x$" - of course new rules have to be introduced when necessary, but the new rules are still finitary. All the math libraries in the world are still finite. Thanks to Newton, Leibniz and many others, differential and integral calculus become largely a (finite) game relating the chain rule with the fundamental theorem w/ some trig sprinkled in.

Comment: @alancalvitti: If you're not going to read what I wrote, I won't bother to answer. Yes, in the case of polynomials you can do this sort of definitions. But how can you do it for very complicated functions? What if you want to prove some general statement about $C^1$ functions? What if you are not an engineer, and you encounter *more* than exponents, logarithms and polynomials?

Comment: I did read your comments. Many (if not "most") integrals don't have closed form solutions. But the rules for manipulating diff/integral calculus expressions symbolically are broader than "polynomials" - eg, here's some related to the symbolic computation of the expected area of (uniform) random triangles in the unit square: http://statigrafix.com/complexity.notes/random.triangle.area.problem/content/integrals.html, http://statigrafix.com/complexity.notes/random.triangle.area.problem/content/regions.html

Comment: But if you insist on things you can represent symbolically then you are limiting yourself very very much. Why would you want to do that when you can give a very swift, clear and general argument? Part of the inherent beauty of mathematics is the generality in which things can be applied. Sure, a layman may not be able to appreciate this, but this is still true. Mathematics is beautiful for its own sake and interest, and one of the beautiful things is its awesome generality rather than a case-by-case similarities.

Comment: It's a tradeoff: clear general arguments are ideal but sometimes don't exist even within maths, eg 4-color map can be reduced to testing whatever ~10k(?) cases. In the random triangle area problem, if you want an exact solution, these are the combinatorics you have to jump through (this is not the same as Monte Carlo sampling). Another example: there are 5 groups of order 8, but ~$10^{10}$ semigroups of order 8. So complexity is a problem also within math, not just the physical world.

Comment: Note that all those  examples are in discrete mathematics. In a branch whose main tools are counting and combinatorics, this is expected.

Comment: Random triangle area --> discrete geometry (actually measure theory as well, but polyhedral so give you the benefit of doubt). 4-color map --> topology. (Inverse) semigroups at least describe the partial symmetries of quasicrystals, pseudoperiodic tilings and many other things. The link between discrete and continuous is deep.

Comment: 4-colors map is a graph theory problem, but sure. You can treat it as a discrete topology problem... Counting semigroups of order $8$, let's see how we *really* ask this mathematically. **How many semigroup structures are there on the set $\{0,\ldots,8\}$? How many are isomorphic?**. It looks pretty darn discrete to me. But sure, go on.

Comment: True, 4CM appeared in J Graph Th - but relates to infinitely many maps correct?. Re semigroups, compare to groups: how many group structures on $\{0,...,8\}$ is similarly discrete but I'm sure you're aware of the implication of the Crystallographic Restriction Theorem, which is 3D geometry. Hey, nature gave us atoms.

Comment: alan, you can't argue over all those threads that everything "important" or "applicable" is discrete and computable, and then take the other side when I argue that *you* are coming from a computational and inherently discrete point of view, and therefore you lack the will/ability/philosophical view required to understand the beauty in generalized mathematical arguments. And this is beyond "continuous" and "discrete". This is about abstract mathematics. Measure theory, if you will, can be applied to both calculus and discrete mathematics. Isn't it amazing?

Comment: What's the expected area of a triangle if the vertices can be varied infinitely (uniformly distributed) in the unit square. Does that refer to a finite set of triangles or infinite set? How many maps can be drawn with 4 colors, finite or infinitely many (despite the use of graph theory in the proof)? - That's what I was referring to by the connection of the discrete and the continuous.

Comment: You got me completely baffled. You want me to argue for mathematical abstractness which will allow you to solve things without computing them, or do you want me to argue that you have to calculate one for triangles in the unit square, and another calculation in a different square, and then another for a slightly different shape, and so on... You'd have to be blind not to **try** and get one general theorem which solves everything without the need to repeat calculations with ever so slight difference. [cont.]

Comment: Let me tell you a [sad] story about the students in faculties of engineering across Israel. You can teach them a very basic theorem about how to solve a class of problems, say some line integral from here to there and so on. Then you will give them an exercise sheet which they will memorize and know how to solve (eventually). Cometh the exam you will add a tiny little twist which is obvious if you just pause one second to think, and they fail almost every time. Why is that? Do you see how that relates to what I said in my previous comment? I think this discussion has gone for long enough...

Comment: That scenario would be familiar around the world, not just Israel. I agree with you and I agree with Conrad Wolfram (http://www.ted.com/talks/conrad_wolfram_teaching_kids_real_math_with_computers.html) that we should free students from the burdens of computation and focus on more abstract and flexible reasoning.

Comment: Nevertheless, earlier you said my example problems were discrete in nature, whereas in reality they refer to uncountably  many geometrical or topological objects, correct?

Comment: Asaf, please answer the above Q, so I know how you understand the issue and what you're talking about when you say "discrete".

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to reply to your last comment. I admit that I somewhat misread your comment with the triangles (and in this barrage of words, I wouldn't blame me). The problems around the first time mentioning were discrete, and then you used "discrete topology" and it threw me off-course completely. In this case, let me just finish by saying that hard analysis is not always "pretty" (nor is category theory or set theory). Some problems are still messy and mathematicians are working on finding the right language to talk about them in a clear way. Usually that entails beautiful abstraction.

Comment: Not just the triangle, but also 4CM - there are uncountably many maps yet 4 colors suffice and the proof is via graph theory, which is discrete. There are uncountably many non-isometric crystals yet finite # of crystal groups. And so on. Thus the link between the continuous and the discrete. All infinities are projected out and you prove things by discrete methods.

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely, infinity has countless (:P) practical applications.

Here's one way to think about it: do negative numbers have any practical applications?

I mean you can't really have a negative amount of anything, can you? You can't have negative five apples.

If your bank balance is negative, that's just another way of saying you owe the bank a (positive amount of) money, rather than the other way around. When we say a particle's charge is negative, we mean only, that it has more of the charge that comes from electrons than the opposite kind that comes from protons. And so on.

Nonetheless, the abstraction of negative numbers - which is to say of the Integers, and of additive inverses and number rings and so on generally - is hugely useful. It pervades our understanding of numbers, both as applied to the real world, and in many of the most theoretical branches of pure mathematics.

The same is true of other mathematical abstractions whose ontology, and thus utility, you might similarly question, from complex numbers to (the very many different forms of) infinity. For instance, infinities underlie all of traditional [real analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_analysis), the foundation of modern calculus and related fields. Whether or not the real numbers are in fact real, in the sense of somehow existing within the universe, they have proven to be at least an incredibly useful approximation for modelling all sorts of things that "may as well" vary continuously at the scales we measure them. There are ongoing efforts to replicate the results of the field using weaker postulates about infinities, in Constructivism and even Finitism, but they are far from being "complete", and probably never will be.

Likewise infinity is at the core of measure theory, on which our current construction of probability is based. Hilbert Spaces, used in the formulation of quantum mechanics, are infinite not just in size, but in dimension. And there are deep links between even the exotic transfinite cardinals of Cantor, and the areas of logic that deal with the most foundational issues of mathematics (and indeed, with those finite but extremely fast growing functions others have mentioned in the context of numbers that are "infinite for any practical purpose.")

Comment: Cardinals are exotic? Neat. I'm sure the Pope will be delighted to hear that!

Comment: @Jordan Rastrick Could you please explain a bit the link between certain infinite cardinals and certain areas of logic. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can take limits of functions as the variable goes to infinity.  In this way you can calculate things like terminal velocity and escape velocity.

Answer (score 2):

Q: What is the largest prime number ?

A: There is none, because the set of primes is infinite.

Proving an *infinite* number of primes isn't so difficult, you prove it by contradiction, i.e. by showing that there cannot be a "last prime", the sequence is *not finite* (the trick is to show that from a given prime deemed the largest one, you can construct another which is... larger). So even though you cannot count  to infinity, you can very well reason about infinity.

Besides ubiquitous appearance in virtually all areas of mathematics, you cannot do without infinity when dealing with continuous phenomena. For instance, you cannot count time, there are too many "instants", and between any two instants there are yet others. By nature, time - and space - cannot be described by finite means (at least as physics currently understands them).

A more abstract usefulness is that working with infinity compells you to find regularity among the studied objects. Working with finite sets in an unstructured/exhaustive way is often possible (for example by means of computers); but infinite collections must somehow be summarized (expressed in comprehension) to become tractable.

Comment: if the concept of infinity is rejected, you can not take a large collection of primes (Super K long) and find another. There would be no more primes than a Super K number of primes. Any larger primes would be invalid, just like the result of dividing by zero.

Comment: @Alexander Ok, if there is no inifinity, then there is no infinity, QED.